# Serve file, log when download is finished

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to save a log of when a large file is downloaded from my server.
The file is served with this method:

```
public IActionResult Download(string filename)
{
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(this.Path + filename,
        FileMode.Open,
        FileAccess.Read,
        FileShare.ReadWrite,
        65536,
        FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan
    );

    return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", filename);
}
```

When the file is finished I want to store a database record of that.

So far my ideas have been to find an event that listens to when a stream disposes or closes, but that doesn't seem to exist. Another idea I had was to compare position of the stream to the length of it, but then I have no idea how to check that.

Answer (score 1):

What if you created a custom stream class that allowed you to log that event?  Something like this:

```
public class MyAwesomeStream : FileStream
{
    //...
    public override Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        //do your event logging / handling here

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    )
}
```

Then just swap that in wherever you were using `FileStream`.

Answer (score 1):

For executing a method after download complete, you could try `ActionFilter`, its `OnActionExecuted` will be called after `Download` method complete.

- FileDownloadCompleteActionFilter.cs

  ```
  public class FileDownloadCompleteActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
      private readonly MVCProContext _context;
      public FileDownloadCompleteActionFilter(MVCProContext context)
      {
          _context = context;
      }
      public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
      {
          base.OnActionExecuted(context);
          //called after executing the action
          _context.Language.Add(new Language {  LanguageName = "L1"});
          _context.SaveChanges();
      }
  }
  ```
- Use method.

  ```
      [TypeFilter(typeof(FileDownloadCompleteActionFilter))]
      public IActionResult About()
      {
          ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

          return View();
      }
  ```